# how to delay the beginning of a clock?

Tags: system-verilog, clock

Using system verilog and new to it and to verilog,
I want to delay the start of clock by 46.666ns in a testbench.
for this I declared another signal, toggled it to 1 after 46.666 and gated my clock with it. however it is not working, and I don't understand why. any help would be very appreciated.
the code I am using:

```
// generate CLKXI and inject to vt
logic clk = 1;
logic clkstart = 0;

initial begin
    #46.666ns clkstart = 1;
end

always 
begin
    if (clkstart && ~clk) #21.25ns clk = ~clk;
    else if (clkstart && clk)  #20.416ns clk = ~clk;
end

assign test_wrapper.dut_top.CLKXI = clk;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is when `clkstart` is 0, your `always` block gets into a zero-delay infinite loop, and time cannot advance. I think what you want is

```
initial begin
    #46.666ns 
    forever begin
         #21.25ns clk = 0;
         #20.416ns clk = 1;
    end
```

Comment: Thanks, this made it work :) however the simulation is running noticeably slower than when it did when I ran it with : `always #21.833ns clk = ~clk`. does it have to do with the forever loop?

Comment: Hard to say when you are comparing something that wasn't working versus what is now working. Do the simulations still end at the same time? Could be the duty cycle difference. The best way to debug performance issues is by using your tool's profiler.